# SIGSEGV and SIGBUS crashes with Xamarin.iOS Unified API

Tags: ios, crash, xamarin, 64-bit

We had a project on Classic API. Everything worked fine for both 32 and 64-bit iOS devices.

Then we migrated to **Unified API**. The application started to crash on some devices (mostly 64-bit devices). It crashes in many different locations and situations. These crashes are hard to predict and reproduce. But a lot of users in production version face this crashes.

Currently we have a version of the app (let's call it Version 1) in production that was build with Xamarin.iOS 8.6 (stable channel) for iOS SDK 8.1.

We have a lot of similar crashes collected with Crittercism (crash reporting service). All crashes are **SIGSEGV (reason: SEGV_MAPERR)**, but may have different stack traces. It looks like some crashes happen only on 64-bit devices.

Then we built another version of the app to reproduce the issue (Version 2). It was built with Xamarin.iOS 8.8 (stable channel) for iOS SDK 8.2 with debug options turned on.

Now we have similar crashes. Most of them happen on background threads (not main UI thread). And now all crashes are **SIGBUS (reason: BUS_ADRERR)**.

What can be the root cause of such crashes? How to diagnose and fix it?

Comment: Currently working on the same problem while upgrading our app. But our app is now crashing during startup. Hope to find the cause soon...
Looks like this: http://webcache.googleusercontent.com/search?q=cache:2AmjpvDpXnsJ:https://bugzilla.xamarin.com/show_bug.cgi%3Fid%3D27147+&cd=5&hl=en&ct=clnk&gl=nl

Comment: @Jacco, our app is also crashing mostly on startup. Today I built app with Xamarin.iOS from Alpha channel (8.8.1.9) and it looks like it solved the problem. But we still didn't test it in production.

Comment: @Jacco, have you tried Alpha channel version. Does it solve the problem?

Comment: thank you for suggesting. We tried, but it still crashes with the same exception. Still trying to narrow it down.

Comment: @Jacco, have you found a solution? BTW, do you get this crash at the same places or each time randomly?

Comment: Finally... For me it was Crittercism v2.1 itself failing on the second launch. Back to v1.1 and everything is running smooth and unified.

Comment: @Jacco, exactly! Same thing in our case.

Answer (score 0):

I faced a similar issue after migrating to Unified API, for me the problem was the dispose of some visual objects in background threads.

This worked fine with Classic API but started to crash after upgrading.

So make sure you are disposing objects on the UI Thread or avoid disposing if not necessary. That could be the reason why the crashes happens on background threads, when objects are collected.

Hope this helps

Comment: It's not the case here. All UI objects are accessed only in UI thread. It looks like new Xamarin.iOS version fixes the problem (8.8.1.9 version from Alpha channel).